# jqgrid navGrid and sort are not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I've been searching for hours and i can't find an answer to my problem.

I'm returning an xml from the server to client; data is displayed correctly inside the jqGrid.
However, sorting isn't working, neither the paging or the search.

When I press the search button in the navGrid the search popup is displayed, but when i press "Find" nothing happens.
Here's my code:

```
<table id="list1"></table>
<div id="pager1"></div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery().ready(function (){
jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({
url:'managenir.do',
datatype: "xml",
 mtype: 'GET',
colNames:['Cod Factura','Nume', 'Data'],
colModel:[
    {name:'id',index:'id', width:75, sortable:true},
    {name:'name',index:'name', width:90, sortable:true},
    {name:'data',index:'data', width:100, sortable:true}    
],
rowNum:10,
autowidth: true,
rowList:[10,20,30],
pager: jQuery("#pager1"),
sortname: 'id',
viewrecords: true,
sortorder: "desc",
caption:"NIR-uri"
})
jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager1',{edit:false,add:false,del:false, search:true});
});
</script>
```

XML returned from server is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><rows><page>1</page><total>1</total><records>3</records><row id='1234'><cell>1234</cell><cell><![CDATA[metro]]></cell><cell>2011-01-24 00:00:00.0</cell></row><row id='444'><cell>444</cell><cell><![CDATA[selgros]]></cell><cell>2011-01-16 00:00:00.0</cell></row><row id='5555'><cell>5555</cell><cell><![CDATA[selgros]]></cell><cell>2011-01-02 00:00:00.0</cell></row></rows>
```

i'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js/jquery-history.js"></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script src="Scripts/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The searching, paging and searching are all done server side. The jqgrid will just reload the grid using your configured url, but it will add extra GET parameters.

The server has to interpret these parameters and return different XML based on them.
[See the jqgrid samples](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). (Loading Data - > XML Data)

For example the typical parameters for sorting and paging are: sidx (sort index), sord (sort direction), page, rows.

So when the server sees sidx and sord, it has to sort the data and return the data to the grid already sorted.